# How to access Windows shell context menu items?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi, shell

In Windows Explorer, you right click on a file, a context menu shows up which contains built-in items like 'Send to...' and/or 3rd party actions such as 'zip file with Winzip'. My question are:

- How to obtain the full list of available menu items for a specific file?
- For each menu item, how to get the caption?
- How to invoke a specific menu item action for a specific disk file?

Thank you in advance!

[EDIT]: While other info is absolutely useful, Delphi solution will be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to create own context menu items or to manipulate existing menu items?

Comment: @Liton, not creating my own shell context menu items, but to manipulate existing menu built-in or 3rd part items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key to obtain the Shell Context menu is use the [`IContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776095%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface.

check this great article [`Shell context menu support`](http://netez.com/2xExplorer/shellFAQ/bas_context.html) for more details.

**UPDATE**

for delphi examples you can see the [JclShell](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid5626A4145356397ABA0FD7CB0AAB44EF3B692ECD.aspx?s=delphi) unit from the JEDI JCL  (check the `DisplayContextMenu` function) and the ShellCtrls unit included in the samples folder of Delphi.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out!

Comment: Hi RRUZ, the DisplayContextMenu funciton from the JCL package does exactly what I want! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer**

Try the [ShellBrowser Components](http://www.jam-software.com/shellbrowser_delphi/) from JAM Software.  They have a component that will let you show Explorer's context menu with your own commands mixed in from a TPopupMenu.

---

**Long answer**

Getting the Explorer menu, querying all of its properties, and hosting them in your own menu is possible, but you really should be comfortable reading/writing low-level Win32 code and a working knowledge of C will help.  You'll also need to watch out for some gotchas (covered below).  I strongly recommend reading Raymond Chen's [How to host an IContextMenu](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/20/231739.aspx) series for a lot of the technical details.

The *easier* approach is to query for the IContextMenu interface, then the HMENU, then use TrackPopupMenu to let have Windows show the menu, then call InvokeCommand at the end.

*Some of the code below is untested or has been modified from what we're using, so proceed at your own risk.*

Here's how you get the [IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776095%28VS.85%29.aspx), for a group of files within a base folder:

```
function GetExplorerMenu(AHandle: HWND; const APath: string;
  AFilenames: TStrings): IContextMenu;
var
  Desktop, Parent: IShellFolder;
  FolderPidl: PItemIDList;
  FilePidls: array of PItemIDList;
  PathW: WideString;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Retrieve the Desktop's IShellFolder interface
  OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop));
  // Retrieve the parent folder's PItemIDList and then it's IShellFolder interface
  PathW := WideString(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(APath));
  OleCheck(Desktop.ParseDisplayName(AHandle, nil, PWideChar(PathW),
    Cardinal(nil^), FolderPidl, Cardinal(nil^)));
  try
    OleCheck(Desktop.BindToObject(FolderPidl, nil, IID_IShellFolder, Parent));
  finally
    SHFree(FolderPidl);
  end;
  // Retrieve PIDLs for each file, relative the the parent folder
  SetLength(FilePidls, AFilenames.Count);
  try
    FillChar(FilePidls[0], SizeOf(PItemIDList) * AFilenames.Count, 0);
    for i := 0 to AFilenames.Count-1 do begin
      PathW := WideString(AFilenames[i]);
      OleCheck(Parent.ParseDisplayName(AHandle, nil, PWideChar(PathW),
        Cardinal(nil^), FilePidls[i], Cardinal(nil^)));
    end;
    // Get the context menu for the files from the parent's IShellFolder
    OleCheck(Parent.GetUIObjectOf(AHandle, AFilenames.Count, FilePidls[0],
      IID_IContextMenu, nil, Result));
  finally
    for i := 0 to Length(FilePidls) - 1 do
      SHFree(FilePidls[i]);
  end;
end;
```

To get the actual menu items you need to call [IContextMenu.QueryContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776097%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You can destroy the returned HMENU using [DestroyMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647631%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
function GetExplorerHMenu(const AContextMenu: IContextMenu): HMENU;
const
  MENUID_FIRST = 1;
  MENUID_LAST = $7FFF;
var
  OldMode: UINT;
begin
  OldMode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS or SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
  try
    Result := CreatePopupMenu;
    AContextMenu.QueryContextMenu(Result, 0, MENUID_FIRST, MENUID_LAST, CMF_NORMAL);
  finally
    SetErrorMode(OldMode);
  end;
end;
```

Here's how you actually call the command that the user has selected from the menu:

```
procedure InvokeCommand(const AContextMenu: IContextMenu; AVerb: PChar);
const
  CMIC_MASK_SHIFT_DOWN   = $10000000;
  CMIC_MASK_CONTROL_DOWN = $20000000;
var
  CI: TCMInvokeCommandInfoEx;
begin
  FillChar(CI, SizeOf(TCMInvokeCommandInfoEx), 0);
  CI.cbSize := SizeOf(TCMInvokeCommandInfo);
  CI.hwnd := GetOwnerHandle(Owner);
  CI.lpVerb := AVerb;
  CI.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  // Ignore return value for InvokeCommand.  Some shell extensions return errors
  // from it even if the command worked.
  try
    AContextMenu.InvokeCommand(PCMInvokeCommandInfo(@CI)^)
  except on E: Exception do
    MessageDlg(Owner, E.Message, mtError, [mbOk], 0);
  end;
end;

procedure InvokeCommand(const AContextMenu: IContextMenu; ACommandID: UINT);
begin
  InvokeCommand(AContextMenu, MakeIntResource(Word(ACommandID)));
end;
```

Now you can use the [GetMenuItemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647980%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to get the caption, bitmap, etc, but a much easier approach is to call [TrackPopupMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932177.aspx) and let Windows show the popup menu.  That would look something like this:

```
procedure ShowExplorerMenu(AForm: TForm; AMousePos: TPoint; 
  const APath: string; AFilenames: TStrings; );
var
  ShellMenu: IContextMenu;
  Menu: HMENU;
  MenuID: LongInt;
begin
  ShellMenu := GetExplorerMenu(AForm.Handle, APath, AFilenames);
  Menu := GetExplorerHMenu(ShellMenu);
  try
    MenuID := TrackPopupMenu(Menu, TPM_LEFTALIGN or TPM_TOPALIGN or TPM_RETURNCMD, 
      AMousePos.X, AMousePos.Y, 0, AForm.Handle, nil);
    InvokeCommand(ShellMenu, MenuID - MENUID_FIRST);
  finally
    DestroyMenu(Menu);
  end;
end;
```

If you actually want to extract the menu items/captions and add them to your own popup menu (we use Toolbar 2000 and do exactly that), here are the other big issues you'll run into:

- The "Send To" menu, and any others that are built on-demand won't work unless you handle messages and pass them to the IContextMenu2/IContextMenu3 interfaces.
- Menu bitmaps are in a couple of different formats.  Delphi doesn't handle Vista high-color ones without coaxing, and the older ones are blended onto the background color using an XOR.
- Some menu items are owner-drawn, so you have to capture paint messages and have them paint to your own canvas.
- Hint strings won't work unless you manually query for them.
- You'll need to manage the lifetime of the IContextMenu and HMENU and only release them once the popup menu has been closed.

Comment: Hi Craig, Thanks for the detailed tech info, they are very helpful! But I have to accept RRUZ's answer because he pointed me to the DisplayContextMenu function from JCL which does exactly what I want with a single line...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exmple how the operating system logic behind the "Send To ... | Mail recipient" context menu item can be used from a Delphi application to open the default mail client, displaying a new mail with the passed (selected) files attached:

[How can I simulate ‘Send To…’ with Delphi?](http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/how-can-i-simulate-send-to-with-delphi/)