# Execute application as context menu action with parameters

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, registry, ui-automation

I want to programatically start an application in the same manner as done when using a specific context menu action, on Windows 10.

[image]

The context menu is provided by the application Proxifier, so from my research I was able to find this in my Registry, which I believe is the related context menu entry.

[image]

However there is only one visible parameter and it seems to be the path to the requested user profile to initialize Proxifier settings.

[image]

Tried a few different combinations and couldn't really figure anything out there... so the other thing I had thought of was examining the window messages sent to Proxifier when clicking the context menu, with Spy++.

Which I've done, I just can't seem to decipher the wParam or lParam or what info I'd send in order to select the correct sub-menu action.

[image]

Any help here would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `%1` refers to the file-system item being acted upon (what you right-clicked on). `%L` seemingly serves the same purpose. `%V` seems to be the most universal form (also works in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background` entries).

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of it, the registry entry I found did not include the %L or %V parameters, only %1. When I run the found command, ...Proxifier.exe "%1" -  %1 is used as a path for the user profile config file. I'm missing the target executable and the corresponding menu action (Proxy, Direct, Block) - not sure how to supply these!

Comment: My understanding is that, at least with the registry-based approach, the only supported variable is the file-system item that the shortcut-menu command was invoked on / or, with `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background` entries, the active directory in File Explorer's view (the only exception is the `printto` verb, in which case `%2` refers to the target printer). Any other parameters will have to be hard-coded. There's also a COM-based way of implementing shortcut-menu commands - see [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to figure out how to get it working by accessing the context menu which I know is technically your question. However, I believe I have a workaround which hopefully could be of use to you.

This workaround involves copying your proxifier profile (which is just an xml formatted file) and creating a new profile. On the new profile we create a new rule with your specified application and desired action (direct,block,proxy) and insert it at the top of the rule list so that the rule is executed first. The application is then launched. The script will wait for the application to be closed and then it will re-select the old profile.

For example running the script to **block** an application would be this:

```
 .\proxifier.ps1 -Block -filePath "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
# the output
Block C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe
Load temp profile    
# will wait until app is closed
Reload original profile # once you close the app
```

The application is added to top of rulelist.

[image]

You will see proxifier loading the new profile and then re-loading the old profile when the application is closed in the proxifier log window.

```
[03.30 11:09:20] Profile test-temp loaded.
[03.30 11:09:32] Profile test loaded.
```

--

The script has these options for rules which are the options for rule actions in proxifier (block,direct,proxy):

```
.\proxifier.ps1 -Block -filePath "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
 .\proxifier.ps1 -Direct -filePath "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
 .\proxifier.ps1 -Proxy -proxyId yourproxyID -filePath "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
```

Proxifier saves your proxy list and has an id for each. So when using the proxy parameter you need the id number for your desired proxy (e.g. 100,101). To get the list run:

```
.\proxifier.ps1 -getProxyID
 
 GetID


id      : 100
type    : HTTPS
Options : 48
Port    : 8080
Address : 127.0.0.1

id      : 101
type    : SOCKS5
Options : 48
Port    : 8080
Address : 10.1.0.1
```

Change the `profilePath` and `savePath` to your desired location. I've tested it and it does successfully set the rules for all actions.

```
# add error handling for incorrect file paths
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=0,ParameterSetName="Block")]    
    [switch]$Block,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=0,ParameterSetName="Direct")]
    [switch]$Direct,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ProxyAction",Position=0)]
    [switch]$Proxy,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ProxyAction")]
    [string]$proxyId,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1,ParameterSetName="Direct")]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1,ParameterSetName="Block")]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1,ParameterSetName="ProxyAction")]
    [string]$filePath,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="proxyID")]
    [switch]$getProxyID

)

#path to the proxifer profile you want to copy (change as desired)
$profilePath = "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Proxifier4\Profiles\fielName.ppx"
#path to existing proxifier exe (change as desired)
$proxifierPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Proxifier\Proxifier.exe"
#save path for temp proxifier profile (change as desired)
$savePath = "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Proxifier4\Profiles\fileName-temp.ppx"

if ($getProxyID){
Write-host "GetID"
[xml]$xmlProxyID = Get-Content -Path $profilePath
Write-Output $xmlProxyID.ProxifierProfile.ProxyList.Proxy 
}
else{
    if ($block){
        $action = "Block" 
    }
    elseif ($direct) {
        $action = "Direct" 
    }
    elseif ($Proxy){
        $action = "Proxy" 
    }
    $ruleName = "My Name" > $null

    Write-Host $action, $filePath
    if (!($filePath.Contains("`""))){
        $filePath = '"{0}"' -f $filePath
    }
# create new element for the rule and set action
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $profilePath
$newElement = $xml.CreateElement("Rule")
$newElement.SetAttribute("enabled","true") 
$childAction = $xml.CreateElement("Action") 
$childAction.SetAttribute("type",$action) 

# set proxy setting if using
if ($proxy){
    $childAction.InnerText = $proxyId 
}

# set application path
$childApplication = $xml.CreateElement("Applications")
$childApplication.InnerText =  $filepath

# $childTargets = $xml.CreateElement("Targets")()
# $childTargets.InnerText = "Any"

# rule name
$childName = $xml.CreateElement("Name")
$childName.InnerText =  $ruleName 

# appened items to element
$newElement.AppendChild($childAction) | Out-Null
$newElement.AppendChild($childApplication) | Out-Null
# $newElement.AppendChild($childTargets)
$newElement.AppendChild($childName) | Out-Null

# insert new element to top of rule list
$topRule = $xml.ProxifierProfile.RuleList.Rule[0] 
$parent = $topRule.ParentNode 
$parent.InsertBefore($newElement,$topRule) | Out-Null
$xml.Save($savePath) | Out-Null

Write-Output "Load temp profile"
Start-Process -FilePath $proxifierPath -ArgumentList $savePath,"silent-load"

# start specified program
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath $filePath -PassThru


# wait until program closes
while (!($proc.HasExited)) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    
}

# re-load original profile
Write-Output "Reload original profile"
Start-Process -FilePath $proxifierPath -ArgumentList $profilePath,"silent-load"



}
```

---

##### This way won't work with proxifier. But could potentially work in certain use cases like in my example here with 7-zip. So i'll just leave this part.

It seems very difficult to access certain items in a file's context menu (or maybe even impossible) in powershell. I am not able to currently install Proxifier but I have been testing with 7-zip. I found [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-work-with-windows-explorer/) which details how to access a file's context menu items in powershell. The issue, which is also mentioned in the post is that some items just can't be accessed easily (items with sub menus don't seem to show up with this method).

An example using the code from the post outputs the following:

```
$o = New-Object -com Shell.APplication
$folder = $o.NameSpace("C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\")
$file = $folder.ParseName("test.zip")

# list file's verbs (context menu items)
$file.Verbs()
# the output
Application Parent Name
----------- ------ ----
                   &Open
                   &test

                   Edit with &Notepad++
                   Share


                   Scan with Sophos Endpoint
                   Restore previous &versions

                   Cu&t
                   &Copy
                   Create &shortcut
                   &Delete
                   Rena&me
                   P&roperties
```

You can see the difference in that output to the screenshot of the context menu of the same file you'll see the "7-zip" option missing. Which most likely would be the case for Proxifier as well:

[image: context menu example]

So, my workaround, although not very elegant is create a [new context menu item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers) (link from @mklement0 comment on your post). The following will create a new context menu item called **customCommand**. It uses the similarly formatted command that you mention but with 7-zip `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe "%1"` to open a file.

```
New-Item -Path  Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand
New-Item -Path  Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand\command
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand\command -name "(default)" -PropertyType String -value "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe `"%1`""
```

Running the above will create the following registry entry:
[image: registry clip]

You can see the new context menu item, **customCommand** is added. It will be added for all files:

[image: context menu example]

Re running the `$file.verbs()` command from above we can see that our new entry is now listed (partial output):

```
Application Parent Name
----------- ------ ----
                   &Open
                   &customCommand # our newly added item
                   &testing
```

Now we can access that item by running:

```
 $file.InvokeVerb("customCommand")
```

Now putting it all together we can:

- create context menu item by adding a registry entry
- run the commands to access and invoke a file's context menu item
- remove the registry entry to clean back up the context menu

The code:

```
#change the folder path and file name
$folderPath = "C:\Users\somepath\Downloads\"
$fileName = "somefile.exe"
#I do not have Proxifier installed but looks like it is similar to the 7-zip command. (copied from your screenshot)
$theCommand = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Proxifier\Proxifier `"%1`""

# example tested working with 7-zip
#$theCommand = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe `"%1`""

if ((Test-Path -LiteralPath $folderPath) -AND (Test-Path -LiteralPath ($folderPath + $fileName))){
if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand)){
    # create registry entries for the contex menu item
    Write-Host "Creating Registery Entry"
    New-Item -Path  Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand | Out-Null
    New-Item -Path  Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand\command | Out-Null
    New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand\command -name "(default)" -PropertyType String -value $theCommand  | Out-Null
}

# access and invoke the context menu item
Write-Host "Opening file with command"
$o = New-Object -com Shell.APplication
$folder = $o.NameSpace($folderPath)
$file = $folder.ParseName($fileName)
$file.InvokeVerb("customCommand") 



    if ((Test-Path -LiteralPath Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand\command)){
        # remove the context menu item
        Write-Host "Removing Registry Entries"
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand\command | Out-Null
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\customCommand | Out-Null
    }
}
else{
    Write-Host "Path doesn't exist. Registry entries not created"
}
```

Output on command line will be the following (and program should launch):

[image: example output]

This theoretically should open Proxifier how you want it to. It should also work with other programs in a similar way if they follow the same format as 7-zip.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I do not see where the application is being executed as the context menu sub-item? It seems the referenced exe is being executed and the supplied parameter is a path to the clicked exe. The issue is, for Proxifier, this supplied parameter is a path to the user profile, which is used for global settings of the program and is mostly indifferent to the clicked context menu sub-item. I'm thinking the solution may be sending messages to the window because the sub-items of Proxifier's context menu will change and are empty if the program is closed.

Comment: Also using Window'd Process Explorer I saw Proxifier isn't being executed with any parameters so I believe the Context menu is just sending a command to proxifier which in return handles everything else including executing the target application.

Comment: @EricBallard dang, was hoping it would be similar enough to the way I got 7-zip working in my test. Well, I'll try to install that program on a computer later today and see if I have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a complete answer, it might guide you.
The proxyfier implements a Shell Extension through a dll.
You can find it at C:\Windows\System32\ProxifierShellExt.dll
Since these are implemented as a [Context Menu Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb776881(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
In summary, you need to host the IContextMenu interface the same way the shell does.
If you are familiar with COM interfaces, and Windows APIs you could give it a try.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721700/call-windows-explorer-shell-extension) answer describes in more detail.
There's also a series from the awesome "The Old New Thing" blog, but the links (found in that answer) doesn't work anymore.
I hope that helps!