# Open Windows Explorer Shell context menu

Tags: c, winapi, windows-shell

How do I enumerate the shell context menu item using Windows API? I need to do it in pure C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unclear to me if you want to show a menu or just enumerate the items, this does the latter (Excluding submenus)

```
HRESULT GetContextMenuForFSItem(PCTSTR path,IContextMenu**ppCM)
{
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlAbs;
    HRESULT hr = SHParseDisplayName(path,0,&pidlAbs,0,0);
    if (!hr)
    {
        IShellFolder*pSF;
        PCUITEMID_CHILD pidlLast;
        hr = SHBindToParent(pidlAbs,&IID_IShellFolder,(void**)&pSF,&pidlLast);
        if (!hr)
        {
            hr = pSF->lpVtbl->GetUIObjectOf(pSF,0,1,&pidlLast,&IID_IContextMenu,0,(void**)ppCM);
            pSF->lpVtbl->Release(pSF);
        }
        ILFree(pidlAbs);
    }
    return hr;
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(0);
    WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
    GetWindowsDirectory(buf,MAX_PATH); /* Arbitrary filesystem item */
    IContextMenu*pCM;
    HRESULT hr = GetContextMenuForFSItem(buf,&pCM);
    if (!hr) 
    {
        HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
        hr = pCM->lpVtbl->QueryContextMenu(pCM,hMenu,0,1,0x7fff,0);
        if (hr > 0)
        {
            UINT c=GetMenuItemCount(hMenu), i=0;
            for (; i<c; ++i)
            {
                GetMenuString(hMenu,i,buf,MAX_PATH,MF_BYPOSITION);
                if (GetMenuState(hMenu,i,MF_BYPOSITION)&MF_SEPARATOR) lstrcpy(buf,_T("--separator--"));
                printf("%.2u=%ws\n",i,buf);
                /*
                Call IContextMenu::GetCommandString  to get the verb 
                or IContextMenu::InvokeCommand to execute
                */
            }
        }
        pCM->lpVtbl->Release(pCM);
        DestroyMenu(hMenu);
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

On my system this prints:

```
00=&Open
01=--separator--
02=S&hare with
03=Restore previous &versions
04=&Include in library
05=--separator--
06=Se&nd to
07=--separator--
08=Cu&t
09=&Copy
10=--separator--
11=Create &shortcut
12=&Delete
13=--separator--
14=P&roperties
```

Using COM in C is not fun, switch to C++ if you can...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do exactly what Explorer does: for the item in question (file, folder, other shell namespace location) you identify the list of shell extensions. These are COM classes and they implement [`IContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. For every shell extension applicable, you can provide your own menu and request that such extension (handler) populates the menu with its additional items (`IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu`).

Later on you are free to decide when, where and if you are going to pop this menu up. Should there a need in handle one of those additional handler's commands, you are responsible to fowrward the command to the handler via `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`. If you for some reason prefer to automate certain command and invoke it without popping up the menu, you can do it as well.

Links you might be interested in:

- [How to access Windows shell context menu items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777121/how-to-access-windows-shell-context-menu-items)
- [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: From where do i get the declaration of the SHELLFOLDER structure?

Comment: Do you mean `IShellFolder`? From API calls, e.g. [`SHGetDesktopFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there a function that creates an IShellFolder object out of a directory path in the Win32 namespace i.e C:\Users\Foo

Comment: Check these code snippets out: http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-105564.html

Answer (score 0):

Raymond Chen wrote an [eleven part series](http://blogs.msdn.com/search/searchresults.aspx?q=IContextMenu&sections=2905) explaining how to do this.  It's really not straightforward.